# Rails Mysql Group by strftime query not working in production

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a query in Rails that is working in development and not in production. The query is:

```
Event.where("created_at > ? AND name = ? AND game = ?", 3.month.ago, Event::TYPE_USER_SESSION, PLATFORM_CODE).group("strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00 UTC', created_at, '-6 days', 'weekday 0')").distinct.count(:user_id)
```

which is translated to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "events"."user_id") AS count_user_id, strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00 UTC', created_at, '-6 days', 'weekday 0') AS strftime_y_m_d_00_00_00_utc_created_at_6_days_weekday_0 FROM "events" WHERE (created_at > '2015-05-05 11:51:32.292908' AND name = 'user_session' AND game = 'LK') GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00 UTC', created_at, '-6 days', 'weekday 0')
```

In **development** **works** with sqlite3, but in production with mysql, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: FUNCTION monkiland.strftime does not exist: SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT `events`.`user_id`) AS count_user_id, strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00 UTC', created_at, '-6 days', 'weekday 0') AS strftime_y_m_d_00_00_00_utc_created_at_6_days_weekday_0 FROM `events` WHERE (created_at > '2015-05-05 11:52:09.879454' AND name = 'user_session' AND game = 'LK') GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00 UTC', created_at, '-6 days', 'weekday 0')
```

In my gemfile

```
group :production do
  gem 'mysql2', '0.3.17'
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Note dont you think **`strftime_y_m_d_00_00_00_utc_created_at_6_days_weekday_0 `** is little longer name?

Comment: Check http://blog.152.org/2009/12/mysql-error-1305-function-xxx-does-not.html

Comment: @PratikCJoshi rails generates it automaticatically

Answer (score 0):

Use Data_Format() Function It is similar to strftime ().

Comment: DATE_FORMAT() will work in production, but not in development. Also, the syntaxis is different. I am not familiar with DATE_FORMAT and I don't know how to group it by week as with stftime() function